# НЕ записывается файл в память телефона

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Нужно загрузить файл с  ftp сервера и сохранить его, но файл почему-то не сохраняется Android API 21

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FTPClient con = null;
                try {
                    con = new FTPClient();
                    con.connect("****");

                    if (con.login("****", "****")) {
                        con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                        con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                        String data = "/storage/emulated/0/11.jpg";

                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
                            boolean result = con.storeFile("/11.jpg", in);
                            in.close();
                            System.out.println("succeeded");
                            if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");

                        }

                        con.logout();
                        con.disconnect();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

манифест

```
package="com.example.ftp_dowload_upload">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Вот зделал, но оно не работает

```
con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                        con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                        String data = "/storage/emulated/0/11.jpg";

                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                            FileOutputStream in = new FileOutputStream(new File(data));
                            boolean result = con.retrieveFile("/11.jpg", in);
                            in.close();
                            System.out.println("succeeded");
                            if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");

                        }

                        con.logout();
                    con.disconnect();
```

Comment: Хм, так вы хотите загрузить файл С ftp-сервера или все-таки загрузить НА ftp-сервер? Судя по коду, вы пытаетесь скорее загрузить файл с устройства на ftp-серевер.

Comment: С FTP сервера загрузить и сохранить

Comment: ну тогда почему вы в коде пытаетесь делать ровно наоброт? `FileInputStream` - получаете входной поток из локального файла (который по ходу и не существует), затем `con.storeFile` - пытаетесь отправить  на сервер. Нужно использовать `retrieveFile`

Comment: все зделал не  работает